# Selecting a location on a map gives wrong coordinates

Tags: xcode, swift, core-location

I am trying to get the coordinates of a point on the map using the touchesBegan function and the tapGesture but the coordinates that I get represent a point different from the selected one on the map. Any help please?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil)
        let touchPoint = tapGesture.locationInView(self.myMap)
        let location = self.myMap.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.myMap)

        let mySpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.5)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, mySpan)
        self.myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        lblLat.text = String(location.latitude)
        lblLng.text = String(location.longitude)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
func tapGestureOnMap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {   
        let touchLocation = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(mapView)
        let locationCoordinate = mapView.convertPoint(touchLocation, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
        print("Tapped at lat: \(locationCoordinate.latitude) long: \(locationCoordinate.longitude)")
}
```

in your `viewDidLoad`, add a `tapGesture` to your mapView, like so:

```
let tapGestureOnMap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapGestureOnMap:")
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureOnMap)
```